# Java function for counting word

Tags: java, data-structures

Is there any default method in Java that can count total occurrence of a word? For example, how many times stack occurred in a string "stack is stack".

Edit: please only Java no third party library.

Comment: By "only Java" do you mean methods which exist in the namespace java.*, or by methods which are written in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in `.matchCount()` method. Here is my impl.

```
public static int matchCount(String s, String find) {
     String[] split = s.split(" ");
     int count = 0;

     for(int i=0; i<split.length; i++){
        if(split[i].equals(find)){
           count++;
        }
     }
     return count;
 }


String s = "stack is stack";
System.out.println(matchCount(s, "stack")); // 2
```

Comment: thanks hilal it works good :) just one type in your program, it should be System.out.println(matchCount(s, "stack")

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StringUtils.countMatches(string, "stack")` from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). This doesn't account for word boundaries, so "stackstack" will be counted as two occurences.

Comment: are you sure StringUtils.countMatches is java function? As long as I know it is third library function

Comment: Thanks but in my question I asked for pure Java function :(

Comment: did you? I don't see such a limitation in the question. And btw, strictly speaking, they are called methods, not functions.

Comment: org.apache.commons is pure java.  you could always look at the source.

Comment: @Bozho, sorry I edited my question. @Anon yes I can call this function but then I have to include this library while I am not writing a big application to use it :)

Comment: @user431276 you can view the source if this class. It is open-source.

Comment: hmm.. looking at the source, at least in commons.lang-2.4, `StringUtils.countMatches("stackstack stack", "stack")` returns 3.  Is this what the OP wants?

Comment: @Anon no idea. I indicated this behaviour, it's up to him to decide whether he wants it or not

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
public static int NumTimesInString(String target, String regex)
{
    return (" " + target + " ").split(regex).length - 1;
}
```

This will work so long as regex doesn't match a beginning or ending space...  Hmm, this might not work for some cases.  You might be better writing a function which uses indexOf

```
public static int NumTimesInString(String target, String substr)
{
    int index = 0;
    int count = -1;
    while (index != -1)
    {
        index = target.indexOf(substr, index);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

NOTE: not tested

Either one can be used as:

```
int count = NumTimesInString("hello world hello foo bar hello", "hello"); 
// count is 3
```

Comment: I highly recommend using the second function over the first

Comment: test it : String s = "a is a asdasd s";
  System.out.println(NumTimesInString(s, "a"));

Comment: @user431276 I wrote my implementation :)